Condition of d so that every connected d-regular bipartite graph is hamiltonian
For what d $ \geq $ 2 can we guarantee that a connected d-regular bipartite graph has a hamiltonian cycle.
I tried using the fact that every d-regular graph can be decomposed into d perfect matchings, using the fact that d-regular graphs contain a perfect matching using Hall's theorem, as long as d $ \geq $ 1. I tried using the d perfect matchings to contruct a hamitonian cycle, but I get stuck here. Can anyone help?

Maybe take inspiration from Dirac's theorem. I suspect the optimal $d$ will be linear in the number of vertices.

I have an example of a bipartite connected non-Hamiltonian graph that gives a $\lceil\frac{n}{6}\rceil$ lower bound on $d$ (The idea is to build a graph where deleting two vertices leaves three connected components). A simple adaptation of dirac's theorem gives an upper bound of $\lceil\frac{n}{4}\rceil$. I suspect the lower bound to be tight, but I'm sure of nothing.

@caduk On the other hand for $d = 2$ we also have such guarantee
